# The nodejs net.createServer function results in a blank server.address value in Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

The net module has a createServer function that allows you to create a network wrapper.  This works fine on a local runtime of Nodejs, but when running in Bluemix it is unable to determine the host address.  The server seems to get created, but upon further inspection I find the server.address to be blank.

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');
var net = require('net');
var tunnelHost = (process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');
var tunnelPort = 8888;
var server;
var gatewayOptions = {
    host: 'http://cap-sg-prd-5.integration.ibmcloud.com/',
    port: '15133',
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.pem')
};

console.log("starting createSecureTunnel");
//create a server end point to use as a network wrapper for the secure gateway
server = net.createServer(function (connListener){
    console.log('net server created');
    connListener.on('end', function() {
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });
    connListener.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
        console.log('exception caught:  ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
    //connect to farside, local/private server
    connectFarside(connListener, function(err, remoteSocket){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('connection made');
        remoteSocket.pipe(connListener);
        console.log('remote socket connecte to local connListener');
        connListener.pipe(remoteSocket);
        console.log('local connListener connected to remote socket');
    });
});


//setup listener for network wrapper
server.listen(tunnelPort, tunnelHost, function(){
    console.log('tunnel created at: ' + tunnelHost +":"+ tunnelPort);  //.address +":"+ server.address().port);
});

//createa a TLS connection to the secure gateway
function connectFarside(conn, callback) {
    console.log("starting connectFarside");
    try {
        console.log("initiating farside connection");
        var socket = tls.connect(gatewayOptions, function(){
            console.log("tunnel connected to " + gatewayOptions.host +":"+ gatewayOptions.port);
            callback(null, socket);
        });
        socket.on("error", function(err){
            console.log("Socket error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        callback(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: As always, when asking questions about code, please include the relevant code you are using and show exactly what diagnostic information you have collected.

Answer (score 2):

Bluemix gives your app a port to run on, this is the reason it is not working in Bluemix.  You are starting to start your app on port `8888` with the following line of code.

```
var tunnelPort = 8888;
```

It should be changed to

```
var tunnelPort = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 8888;
```

The above line will read an environment variable called `VCAP_PORT` where Bluemix assigns a port to your app, if it is not running Bluemix it will run on port `8888`.

Your app will be accessible over the web on port `80` and `443`.  Bluemix will load balance to your app for you.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and if I use the process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT then I don't need the require("cf-autoconfig").

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the server address when listening to the server

```
var net = require('net')
var server = net.createServer(handler)

server.listen(port, address)
```

Try with `address = '0.0.0.0'` and see if it works

Comment: I didn't know you could add the address, thanks!  So, problem still is since this is running on Bluemix I need to have the address to use for Bluemix.  I have tried using the address of my app, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Just to clarify, the code works fine when running from a local machine.  The problem is when I try to run this from Bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved by using the cf-autoconfig module.  It helps to reconfigure modules for use on Cloud Foundry platforms.  By including this as the first line in my app, it mostly works.  It doesn't use the port number. But at least I can access the wrapper.

So I added this as the first line

```
require("cf-autoconfig");
```

Then I changed the server.listen to this

```
//setup listener for network wrapper
server.listen(tunnelPort, function(){
    console.log('tunnel created at: ' + tunnelHost +":"+ tunnelPort);  //.address +":"+ server.address().port);
});
```

Now if I use my app name, I can connect to the server created by net.createServer().

I would still like to know how to get the port to work, so this can be used inside of a web application to provide the tunneling.